# How To Write an Image Using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, file

I want to know that how can I write an image using `FileOutputStream` as because `FileOutputStream` is used for byte data like image,video and audio otherwise for text data its better and sufficient to use `FileReader` and `FileWriter` so what I want to do is I have an img.png file and i am able to read it using

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\img.png"));
```

and reading it using `read` method and at that time i want to create a same image with different name using

```
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\newimg.png"));
```

and writing them with `fout.write` but when i do that image is created but not able to see it and its size is in bytes

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fileinputstreamexample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 *
 * @author Love Poet
 */
public class FileInputStreamExample {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\img.png"));
        int i;
        while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
        {
            fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\newimg.png"));
            fout.write(i);
            fout.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("File readed Succesfully");
        System.out.println("File Written Succesfully");
        fout.close();
        fin.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the full code, where you're doing the reading and writing

Comment: hi its ok i found my mistake well thanks for your effort my mistake was that i  was creating the new image again and again in the loop :-) my coding is increasing day by day very good :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DownloadImage {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        FileInputStream in = null;
        int cursor;
    try{
        in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\ganesh.r\\Desktop\\My Stuff\\dp.jpeg"));
        out = new FileOutputStream("TestImage.jpeg");
        while((cursor = in.read())!=-1){
            out.write(cursor);
        }
    }
    finally{
        if(in!=null){
            in.close();
        }
        if(out!=null){
            out.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Read and Write complete");
    }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\img.png")); 
    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\newimg.png"));

        int content;
        while ((content = fin.read()) != -1) {
            fout.write(content);
         }

        System.out.println("Finished");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the opening of file to outside of the loop.

Instead of

```
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
        {
            fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\newimg.png"));
            fout.write(i);
            fout.flush();
        }
```

Do this

```
fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\newimg.png"));
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
        {
            fout.write(i);
            # flush inside loop only if the chunks u r reading are HUGE, and u want+accomodate to partial flush.
        }
       fout.flush();
```

Comment: Don't flush inside loops.

Answer (score 0):

You're recreating the file for every byte input.

The following is considerably more efficient than all the byte-wise solutions posted so far:

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\img.png")); 
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Folder1\\newimg.png"));

int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more if you like
while ((count = fin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Try using to add images in word file-

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();


    run.addBreak();
    run.setText("Name File-test" );
    run.addBreak();


    String image;
    String testpath;
    File file = new File("Path\\Images\\");
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        int format = Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;

        if (f.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
            image = f.getName();
            testpath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            // System.out.println(testpath);
            // System.out.println(image);
            run.addBreak();
            run.setText(image);
            run.addBreak();
            run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(testpath), format, testpath, Units.toEMU(400), Units.toEMU(500));
        }
    }
   FileOutputStream wordDoc =
        new FileOutputStream("Path- .docx");
    document.write(wordDoc);
    wordDoc.close();
```